# Attribute "Width" of <table> tag does not work properly in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have been working in an html email template. And I am almost at the end of my work. The template looks pretty good in mayor email clients. But there is a problem with Outlook 2007/2010/2013. Those three guys do not respect the max width of my template. I do not really know why this happens.

Do you have any idea? 
Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<body style="margin:0; font-size:13px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Verdana, Arial;" bgcolor="#bb9dd8">   

    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">     
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#bb9dd8">

            <!-- //Begin Main Container\\  -->              
                <table class="mainContainer" style="margin-top:20px;" width="640px"  align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

        <!-- //From here begin header and the layout structure\\  -->
```

That was the piece of code where the max width is defined. Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem ? is it less than 100% or more ? if more, use table-layout:fixed; in order to freeze the width of your table

Comment: Thanks you. What is the idea? To fix the table to an specific size? Anyway if was asking about the problem with Outlook. Is that the template takes more than 640px which is the max width that want.

Comment: the idea is that, witouht complete code of yours, i pointed at this http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout. Beside, for outlook, you could try to use width:expression(...) wich old IEs(<8) understood and used to emulate on the fly all kind of calculation or condition (js inside) in CSS.  see this http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/ie/ie6-min-max-height-width.php or any other link you find with "IE CSS EXPRESSION" like http://mark-story.com/posts/view/css-expressions-in-ie-and-scoping from https://www.google.fr/search?q=ie+css+expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, PC versions of Outlook 2007+ do not support max-widths. You can take one of two approaches here to achieve a fluid width, though.

Use some Outlook conditional code to establish a fixed width table. This will be ignored by other email clients.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <table width="640" style="width:640px">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <![endif]-->
                Put main content table here
              <!--[if gte mso 9]>
           </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
     <![endif]-->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another approach involves using a media query, and a 3 column table. The outer columns will have non-breaking spaces, and the middle will be set to your Outlook width and contain your main table.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  .maxW {width: 640px !important;}
}
</style>
<table align="center" width="100%" >
   <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td align="center"  valign="top" width="640" style="width:640px" >
         <table align="center" style="margin: auto; max-width: 640px" width="100%" class="maxW">
            <tr>
               <td>Put your header image here</td>
```

Comment: Thank you @BillMalcolm. I understand. The idea is to use media query to grab the size that outlook sets automatically and force it to get the size that I want (640px). 
But the point is that as you can see in my code above I have a:
`1st level table  ----> width=100% (which is the whole screen)
   2nd level table  ----> width=640px (which is the template itself)` 
From this point all the <td> are restricted to the same width, which is the size that I want. 
Why I need to specify the size for 640px or bigger in Outlook? 
Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Do you have a link to your code? Any number of things could be blowing out your table. An improperly sized image, a string of unbroken characters such as a URL, etc. Create a fiddle or post a link and I'll take a look

Answer (score 2):

just remove px from width and you can try using width="640" instead of width="640px"

Answer (score 0):

Either wrap in a defined table in Mso conditional or set an ID with a defined width in style sheet that changes back to percent in media queries. Outlook does not respect max-width. See [here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for CSS compatability.

Also - you do not put the px when defining the HTML width. That is only in CSS. E.g. Width="640" not width="640px"